# Migrating JBoss JAAS to Spring Boot 2 security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm migrating a JBoss application to Spring Boot (removing JBoss).
In JBoss I had JAAS configured in login-config.xml as follows:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<!-- The XML based JAAS login configuration read by the
org.jboss.security.auth.login.XMLLoginConfig mbean. Add
an application-policy element for each security domain.

The outline of the application-policy is:
<application-policy name="security-domain-name">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="login.module1.class.name" flag="control_flag">
      <module-option name = "option1-name">option1-value</module-option>
      <module-option name = "option2-name">option2-value</module-option>
      ...
    </login-module>

    <login-module code="login.module2.class.name" flag="control_flag">
      ...
    </login-module>
    ...
  </authentication>
</application-policy>

$Id: login-config.xml 87078 2009-04-09 14:23:47Z bstansberry@jboss.com $
$Revision: 87078 $
-->

<policy>
  <!-- Used by clients within the application server VM such as
  mbeans and servlets that access EJBs.
  -->
  <application-policy name="MyClientLoginDomain">
    <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule" flag="required">
        <!-- Any existing security context will be restored on logout -->
        <module-option name="restore-login-identity">true</module-option>
        <!-- <module-option name ="multi-threaded">true</module-option>  -->
        <!-- <module-option name ="password-stacking">useFirstPass</module-option> -->
      </login-module>
    </authentication>
  </application-policy>

  <!-- The default login configuration used by any security domain that
  does not have a application-policy entry with a matching name
  -->
  <application-policy name="other">
    <!-- A simple server login module, which can be used when the number
    of users is relatively small. It uses two properties files:
    users.properties, which holds users (key) and their password (value).
    roles.properties, which holds users (key) and a comma-separated list of
    their roles (value).
    The unauthenticatedIdentity property defines the name of the principal
    that will be used when a null username and password are presented as is
    the case for an unuathenticated web client or MDB. If you want to
    allow such users to be authenticated add the property, e.g.,
    unauthenticatedIdentity="nobody"
    -->
       <authentication>
          <login-module code = "com.mycomp.view.system.security.loginmodule.MyLoginModule" flag = "required" >
          </login-module>
       </authentication>

  </application-policy>

  <application-policy name = "MyServerLoginDomain">
       <authentication>
          <login-module code = "com.mycomp.view.system.security.loginmodule.MyLoginModule" flag = "required" >
          </login-module>
       </authentication>
  </application-policy>

</policy>
```

Since I'm ditching JBoss, I'm trying to implement Spring Security JAAS using the same login modules (but not JBoss login module).
**My Spring Configuration:**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        Map<String, AppConfigurationEntry[]> mappedConfigurations = new HashMap<>();        

        String securityDomainName = "MyServerLoginDomain";
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        AppConfigurationEntry myAppConfig = new AppConfigurationEntry(MyLoginModule.class.getName(), LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, options);

        mappedConfigurations.put(securityDomainName, new AppConfigurationEntry[] { myAppConfig });
        InMemoryConfiguration memoryConfig = new InMemoryConfiguration(mappedConfigurations, new AppConfigurationEntry[] { myAppConfig });
        DefaultJaasAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DefaultJaasAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setConfiguration(memoryConfig);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);

        javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.setConfiguration(memoryConfig);
    }
}
```

**My question is:** How can I convert the JBoss login module "[org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Using_JBoss_Login_Modules-ClientLoginModule.html)" to Spring ?
I cannot use JBoss classes since I'm removing JBoss (migrating to Spring Boot 2.1), so I need some kind of an alternative login module.
This login module is used for an internal login of a special user named "task" which I use internally.
And I need to do this login to user "task" before I populate the database with users and roles, so I can't use "MyLoginModule" class (which is doing a database authentication).
My use of "MyClientLoginDomain" looks like this:

```java
public class MyLoginContext {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger();

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> usernameThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    private final String uname ;
    private final String upasswd ;
    private final LoginContext lc ;

    public MyLoginContext(String username, String password) {
        try {
            lc = new LoginContext("MyClientLoginDomain", new UsernamePasswordCallbackHandler(username, password.toCharArray()));
            this.uname = username ;
            this.upasswd = password;
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e) ;
        }
    }
    public MyLoginContext() {
        this("task", "task") ;
    }
    public void login() throws LoginException {
        lc.login(); 
        usernameThreadLocal.set(uname);
        logger.debug("Set usernameThreadLocal to " + uname);
    }
    public void logout() throws LoginException {
        lc.logout();
        usernameThreadLocal.set(null);
        logger.debug("Set usernameThreadLocal to " + null);
    }
.
.
.
```

```java
class UsernamePasswordCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {
    private transient String username;
    private transient char[] password;

    public UsernamePasswordCallbackHandler(String username, char[] password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            Callback c = callbacks[i];
            if ((c instanceof NameCallback)) {
                NameCallback nc = (NameCallback)c;
                nc.setName(this.username);
            } else if ((c instanceof PasswordCallback)) {
                PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback)c;
                pc.setPassword(this.password);
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to figure out a way to do that? I have a similar requirement.. I am migrating my app from WebSphere login module to Spring Security so I won't be able to make use WebSphere jars

Comment: Hi, I am still looking for an approach @tiktok if you got any, please share that with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GovindKumarThakur: Please elaborate a little bit what you need and I may be able to help Or post another question.

Comment: What ever asked in the question above I need similar to implement. Let me give you some context, currently my app is deployed on jboos and we are defining Login module in jboos standalone.xml and using that Login module in sprint Boot app, now we are planning to migrate it to spring boot jar app, so there won't be jboos dependency, Now please help me in implementing the same in spring boot app.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what I did but here is what I remember - some context here .. My app (In spring boot + tomcat) was sending credentials to another app which was deployed on websphere and verfying those credentials so I created custom loginModule in springboot app and you have to save your customlogin module name with required=true in some properties file.. create a jar file and place it in websphere and register your customlogin module.. so when you pass the credentials from your springboot app your custom login module will verify it as per the logic written in it and it should work.